# jQueryMobile button down color

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova

I have a button defined as:

```
    <a id="myBtn" href="" data-role="button">Logon</a>
```

And I have a tap event associated with the button. However when tapped it does not change to ui-btn-down-c theme color. Note that if it has an href like this it works.

```
    <a id="myBtn" href="logon.html" data-role="button">Logon</a>
```

I cannot use this in my app so this workaround is no good for me. Any thoughts on why this does not work. Also I have set the background for the button inside the tap event handler but there is a serious lag before it turns that color (at least in iOS) in PhoneGap.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The delay exist to allow for double tapping and tap and hold etc. It is usually a 500ms to 700ms delay. To work around this delay try binding to touchstart. Example:

```
$('#myBtn').on('touchstart',function(){
    $(this).addClass('ui-btn-down-c');
});
```

Please note that this won't work in some phone browsers(WP7, blackberry). But It should work fine in IOS

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately I need one soure for all platforms including Blackberry.

Comment: Thanks, and yes I have tried that and it is indeed fast but it also has the side effect of firing the event when a user is scrolling/sliding the page up or down.